# Could not instantiate new WebDriver instance of type class

Tags: selenium, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

**Working:-**

Browser: Chrome,
Version: 102.0.5005.63,
Driver version: 102.0.5005.61.exe,
Selenium Version: 4.0.0

**Not Working:-**

Browser: Edge,
Version: 102.0.1245.33,
Driver version: 102.0.1245.33.exe (Tested with both X86 and 64),
Selenium Version: 4.0.0

I am getting the following error while running my automation pack in edge driver. The same works perfectly fine with chrome browser.

```
19:51:28.482 [main] ERROR  -     Could not instantiate new WebDriver instance of type class org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver (The path to the driver executable The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.edge.driver system property; for more information, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/. The latest version can be downloaded from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/). See below for more details.
```

**Runner.java:-**

```
package Global.ExecutionManager;

import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import net.serenitybdd.cucumber.CucumberWithSerenity;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin = {"pretty"},
        features = "Test",
        glue = "foo"
)
public class TestRunner {

}
```

**Feature**

```
Feature: foo boo.

  Scenario: test
    Given Login with valid "foo" credentials
```

**Step definition file:-**

```
import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import net.thucydides.core.annotations.Step;
import net.thucydides.core.pages.PageObject;

import java.sql.SQLException;

public class credentails extends PageObject {


public credentails() throws SQLException {
}

@Step
@Given("^Login with valid \"([^\"]*)\" credentials$")
public void login_with_valid_credentials(String userType) throws InterruptedException {
    open();
    // line of codes.
}
```

}

**Serenity.properties:-**

```
webdriver.chrome.driver=foo/boo/ChromeDriver_32_102.0.5005.61.exe
webdriver.edge.driver=foo/boo/EdgeDriver_32_102.0.1245.33.exe
```

**Execution in CMDLine:**

```
mvn test install -Denv="Dev" -Dwebdriver.driver=edge
```

**Expected Results:**

Browser should launch successfully.

**Actual Results:**

Could not instantiate class org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver

**Log details:-**

```
20:08:30.962 [main] DEBUG io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.Shell - Running command on the shell: [wmic, datafile, where, name='C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe', get, Version, /value]
20:08:31.179 [main] DEBUG io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.Shell - Result: Version=102.0.1245.33
20:08:31.179 [main] DEBUG io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - Edge (based on Chromium) version 102 found
20:08:31.179 [main] DEBUG io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - Getting driver version for edge102 from online versions.properties
20:08:31.924 [main] DEBUG io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - Driver for edge102 not found in online properties (using local version)
20:08:31.924 [main] DEBUG io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - The driver version for Microsoft Edge 102 is unknown ... trying with latest
20:08:31.924 [main] DEBUG io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - Reading https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/ to find out the latest version of Edge driver
20:08:40.020 [main] WARN io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - There was an error managing msedgedriver (latest version) (null) ... trying again using mirror
20:08:40.036 [main] DEBUG io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.Shell - Running command on the shell: [wmic, datafile, where, name='C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe', get, Version, /value]
20:08:40.219 [main] DEBUG io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.Shell - Result: Version=102.0.1245.33
20:08:40.219 [main] DEBUG io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - Edge (based on Chromium) version 102 found
20:08:40.220 [main] DEBUG io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - Getting driver version for edge102 from online versions.properties
20:08:40.220 [main] DEBUG io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - Driver for edge102 not found in online properties (using local version)
20:08:40.221 [main] DEBUG io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - The driver version for Microsoft Edge 102 is unknown ... trying with latest
20:08:40.225 [main] DEBUG io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - Reading https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/ to find out the latest version of Edge driver
```

Answer (score 0):

It appear that your browser was updated then you Edge Driver got obsolete, you need to update you driver manually downloading again.

You should use automatic driver download using serenity.conf

```
webdriver {
  driver = chrome
}
```